# What is the difference between gtk_icon_view_set_markup_column and gtk_icon_view_set_text_column?

Tags: gtk

What is the difference between [gtk_icon_view_set_markup_column](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.1/GtkIconView.html#gtk-icon-view-set-markup-column) and [gtk_icon_view_set_text_column](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.1/GtkIconView.html#gtk-icon-view-set-text-column)?

According to the documentation, markup overrides the text, but I wasn't able to figure out what markup was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried, but let me guess… Maybe `gtk_icon_view_set_markup_column` allows to use some markup text like "`<b>text</b>`". See [pango markup format](http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html). The "markup" word in GTK documentation refers to that, like in the [gtk_label_set_markup](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.1/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-markup) documentation for example.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware about markup. It's a great thing to know.